# Is there a way to hide a embed in discordjs v14 and unhide it later?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a embed built in a commands execute function and I want it to only be shown when a button is clicked. I have it half working right now but the issue is that the embed is shown by default and again whenever the button is clicked.

Is there any way to hide the embed until the button is clicked? Or is there anyway to include "hidden" data to the embed so I can access it inside of InteractionCreate events? I cannot simply move all the embed creation logic into index.js because the data is a response from an API and I don't save it. Additionally, I'd like to avoid implementing a database.

index.js:

```
if (interaction.isButton()) {
  if (interaction.customId === "get_image_generation_data") {
    // Get the embed from the message the button is attached to
    const embed = interaction.message.embeds[0];

    // Send the image generation data as an ephemeral message
    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
}
```

command.js:

```
// Call API
let data = await response.json();
const fields = Object.entries(JSON.parse(data.images.info))

// Create embed
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor(0x0099ff)
  .setTitle("txt2img")
  .addFields(fields)
  .setTimestamp();

// Create the button and action row for the "get image generation data" button
const getGenerationDataButton = new ButtonBuilder()
  .setCustomId("get_image_generation_data")
  .setLabel("Get Image Generation Data")
  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(getGenerationDataButton);

// Reply with the embed and the file attachment
await interaction.editReply({
  embeds: [embed],
  files: files,
  components: [actionRow],
});
```

Comment: _Is there any way to hide the embed until the button is clicked?_ You could just edit the original message on the button click and add the embed, couldn't you?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Yes you can. I wasn't sure if there was a way to store "hidden" data inside the reply, and I don't think there is. For now I will store the embed in memory in a global map with the interaction ID as the key.